# Doctrine Inheritance replacement

Tags: inheritance, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Currenty we're developing a very flexible and modular application with Zend Framework 2 and Doctrine 2. In this application there are multiple Doctrine entities, for example let's say the entity `Product` in the module `Products`. This module `Products` is the base/default module for product management.

We want to be able to create a custom `Products` module for a customer (`XProducts`). Therefore I created a new entity, `XProduct` (with some extra fields) which extends `Product`.

So if the custom module is enabled I want to use `XProduct` and else `Product`, but never together (in the same project).

If I annotate both entities with @Entity it works partially; for example `findAll` works perfect, but `find` doesn't work: the created SELECT statement contains the correct columns, but the WHERE clause is wrong. For example:

```
SELECT t1.id AS id2, t1.name AS name3 FROM products t1 WHERE t0.id = ?
```

I guess `t1` stands for `ProductX` and `t0` for `Product` but I can't figure out why the columns are correct (`t1`) but the where clause isn't (`t0`).

I'm aware that Doctrine provides Single Table Inheritance to achieve inheritance, but therefore it's necessary to have a DiscriminatorColumn and to define the DiscriminatorMap at the base/default entity. This won't fit for us, because we need to change our base/default module if we add a new custom module for a customer (and that's not what we want...).

Does anyone have a clue on fixing this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally fixed this problem. For all default/base class I created an extra abstract MappedSuperclass (as Jurian Sluiman mentioned). For example, for a specific `Product` entity for a customer I need the following:

- AbstractProduct (contains all default/base functionalities)
- Product (default/base class which is empty and extends AbstractProduct)
- XProduct (which contains extra functionalities for our customer and extends AbstractProduct)

To fix the problems with associations on a MappedSuperclass I refer to the abstract class, for example:
`@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="ProductManagement\Entity\AbstractProduct")`

I then use Doctrine's EntityResolver (see http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/resolve-target-entity-listener.html) to map an abstract class (or interface) association to a real entity (depending on the configuration):

```
'entity_resolver' => array(
    'orm_default' => array(
        'resolvers' => array(
            // Note: Use only one
            'ProductManagement\Entity\AbstractProduct' => 'ProductManagement\Entity\Product', // Default
            'ProductManagement\Entity\AbstractProduct' => 'XProductManagement\Entity\XProduct', // For customer X
        )
    )
)
```

This way I'm able to override my entities with specific entities for my customers, without changing the default/base module and entities (which is exactly what I was looking for).

Comment: I'm trying the same approach but the problem is that the abstract entity class (AbstractProduct) can not be used in DQL queries. According to the [manual](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) mapped superclasses are not query-able. How do you write queries that work both for Product and XProduct?

Answer (score 3):

We use this pattern as well as it's with Doctrine the easiest to work with (though it can be made OOP wise much better with a lot of ugly code). Take an example of our [Portfolio](https://github.com/Soflomo/Portfolio) module where a `Portfolio` instance can take up multiple `Item` instances.

We work with a `Portfolio` entity which extends from the mapped superclass `AbstractPortfolio`. If we have a client requiring a special field, we create a `ClientPortfolio` extending the mapped superclass, so it overloads all properties correctly.

The class name is [specified in the config](https://github.com/Soflomo/Portfolio/blob/master/config/module.config.php#L43) and that string is used in for example the [factory for the repository](https://github.com/Soflomo/Portfolio/blob/master/src/Soflomo/Portfolio/Factory/PortfolioRepositoryFactory.php#L53). You never load the `Portfolio` repository, but always load the `ClientPortfolio` even when you request the repository class from the service manager under the name of the default portfolio.

This method can work fine with repository functions [like here](https://github.com/Soflomo/Portfolio/blob/master/src/Soflomo/Portfolio/Repository/Item.php#L53) (though this class is the repository for an `Item` and not the `Portfolio`). I would not use single table inheritance as you do not use multiple entities besides each other. At least, that is our case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A MappedSuperclass sounds interesting, although I then need to create extra classes for all entities (abstract and default/base class). But if it works; it's okay :). There's only one problem: a MappedSuperclass can't have One-To-Many and One-To-One relations and that's exactly what I wan't; for example a `ProductGroup` has a parent property referencing itself. So I think using a MappedSuperclass isn't possible.

Comment: I'm on my mobile now, so can't check it easily, but above portfolio module has a portfolio container with items in it, having the proper relations (that's one to many). Check the Github repository, there should be something in there to make this work.

Comment: The only relation I can find in your module is a Many-To-One relation in AbstractItem to Portfolio. Of course on the other side it's a One-To-Many relation, but in my situation I want to define the relation at this side, which won't work on a MappedSuperclass.