# Symfony - Optional inheritance with Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

We encounter an issue with inheritance on Symfony 5.

We created a **UserBundle** bundle which includes a simple `User` entity (*id, email, password*): the purpose of this bundle is to be able to easily reimport it into our various projects.

In some projets, we want to extend this entity to add some specific fields (*phone, address, ...*), but that's not always the case.

Here is the code we had set up:

**UserBundle > User class:**

```
<?php

namespace MyCompany\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
* @ORM\MappedSuperclass()
*/
class User implements UserInterface
{
   /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    ...
```

**User entity inherited:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use MyCompany\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"})
*/
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $phone;

    ...
```

The inheritance works fine: **the problem comes from projects for which the `User` entity of the bundle is sufficient for us**.
=> The `User` class of the bundle is defined as `Mapped superclass` in order to be able to extend it but Doctrine can't create an associated table if there is no class which inherits from it...

We could systematically create an empty `User` class in *src/* which inherits from the `User` class of the bundle, but that doesn't seem super clean to me...

I went on this post but that doesn't seem to work: [Doctrine Inheritance replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588682/doctrine-inheritance-replacement)

Could anyone help us on this problem? I imagine that a solution must exist...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Requiring each app to have their own User class probably is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

The idea below does not work.

As @Cerad already pointed out, the best approach probably really is to define the concrete `User` in each app. Thats also what FOSUserBundle does.

---

<s>I'd go with the following approach: Declare the mapped superclass abstract.</s>

```
/**
* @ORM\MappedSuperclass()
*/
abstract class AbstractBaseUser implements UserInterface
{
   /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    ...
```

And implement a concrete empty child class `User` inside your bundle.

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class User extends AbstractBaseUser
{
}
```

That way each app can either use the `User` of your library or inherit from it.

Comment: Thanks! We already tried, but when we do a `bin/console make:migration`, Doctrine refuses saying that `the user table already exists`, which makes sense because we have then two `User` classes defined as entities. The answer may be obvious but is there a solution to force Doctrine to choose an entity or the other according to our projects?

Comment: @AlexandreO so true. Of course, i updated my answer. Without digging to deep, a feasible approach might be to define the orm mapping in yaml instead of annotations. The consumer of the bundle should then be able to override the configuration.